# Copiable Label/TextField/LabeledText in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I just want to create copiable label in JavaFX.
I have tried to create TextField that have no background, have no focus border and default background color, but I have no success. 
I have found a lot of questions how to remove focus background from control but all of that looks like "hacks".

Is there are any standard solution to implement copyable text?

Comment: There's no standard way, but there's been [a bug filed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091997) to change that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a TextField without the border and background color with css:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CopyableLabel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField copyable = new TextField("Copy this");
        copyable.setEditable(false);
        copyable.getStyleClass().add("copyable-label");

        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(copyable, tf2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("copyable-text.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and

copyable-text.css:

```
.copyable-label, .copyable-label:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0px ;
}
```

Comment: I'm ubable to do same thing on Label or pane. Is there anyway to do this

Comment: How do we get rid of the context menu?

Comment: @MouseEvent, here's [how to get rid of the context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125350/5432315)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used, where there is a small button besides the label to be able to copy the text:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.FontAwesome;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph;

import java.util.Locale;

public class CopiableLabel extends Label
{
    public CopiableLabel()
    {
        addCopyButton();
    }

    public CopiableLabel(String text)
    {
        super(text);
        addCopyButton();
    }

    public CopiableLabel(String text, Node graphic)
    {
        super(text, graphic);
    }

    private void addCopyButton()
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.visibleProperty().bind(textProperty().isEmpty().not());
        button.managedProperty().bind(textProperty().isEmpty().not());
        button.setFocusTraversable(false);
        button.setPadding(new Insets(0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 4.0));
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> AppUtils.copyToClipboard(getText()));
        Glyph clipboardIcon = AppUtils.createFontAwesomeIcon(FontAwesome.Glyph.CLIPBOARD);
        clipboardIcon.setFontSize(8.0);
        button.setGraphic(clipboardIcon);
        setGraphic(button);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
    }
}
```