# How to enable right click option in JavaFX Pane?

Tags: java, javafx, right-click

I want to copy all text or selected text from Pane for that I haven't found any function in javaFX. And that copied string/text should be paste into OS files or such place where I can paste. Any Idea would be appriciated. 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534067/copiable-label-textfield-labeledtext-in-javafx help?

Comment: You didn't understand my question.

Comment: So explain it better. I thought you wanted to display text, and allow the user to be able to select and copy it.

Comment: How exactly is your question to be understood? In the header you want a right click option, in the text you want to copy something from a container? Also, how is this rather primitive question upvoted 3 times in such a short time?

Comment: @James_D you understand exactly what I want  but I followed that you given link that did not work on Pane and Label Node.

Comment: The whole point of that post is that you can achieve what you want with a text field.

Comment: @James_D adjactly sir that post is about TextField only but I want to do same thing on Label or any pane.

Comment: Use a TextField *instead* of the Label.