# I am making a new form using JavaFX. I need a Pop up text field within the form to add new category

Tags: forms, javafx

[adding new category within the same window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43275.png)

I am making a new form using javafx to add new item to an inventory, if I need to add new category into the Item form, I must be able to do within the frame itself by popping up a new text field as shown in the red box. Is there any way to do the same in JavaFX?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173811/how-to-make-a-javafx-label-selectable/44182371#44182371) for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different approaches. You could use a `TextField` and `setEditable(false)`. Then make the `TextField`'s `setEditable(true)` after a double-click on the `TextFeild`. The first half of the code shows this approach. Another option is to use a `Label`. When the `Label` is double-clicked, hide the `Label` and show a `TextField` or `TextArea`. Type your data into one of these nodes and when enter is pressed, remove the `TextField` or `TextArea` and show the text in your `Label`. The second half of the code show this approach.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication7 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        VBox root = new VBox();
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        TextField textField = new TextField("Text");
        textField.setEditable(false);//Set Editiable to false

        textField.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
                    if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                        textField.setEditable(true);//On double click set editable to true

                        textField.setOnKeyPressed(event ->{
                            if(event.getCode().toString().equals("ENTER"))
                            {
                                textField.setEditable(false);//On enter set editable to false
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Label label = new Label("Test");
        VBox.setVgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
        label.wrapTextProperty().set(true);

        label.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
                    if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                        label.setVisible(false);
                        TextArea textarea = new TextArea(label.getText());
                        textarea.setPrefHeight(label.getHeight() + 10);
                        stackPane.getChildren().add(textarea);

                        textarea.setOnKeyPressed(event ->{
                            System.out.println(event.getCode());
                            if(event.getCode().toString().equals("ENTER"))
                            {
                                label.setText(textarea.getText());
                                stackPane.getChildren().remove(textarea);
                                label.setVisible(true);                               
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        stackPane.getChildren().add(label);   

        root.getChildren().add(textField);
        root.getChildren().add(stackPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }       

}
```