# How to align text vertically in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, textarea

I have `TextArea` in `JavaFX`. I need to align text vertically or make `TextArea` to be same size as content. Currently, `TextArea` is growing to fill its parent height.
[image]

Comment: If you will not be editing the texting, use a `Label`.

Comment: I need text to be selectable, that's why I went for `TextArea`

Comment: If no one posts a solution, you can look at these workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173811/how-to-make-a-javafx-label-selectable/44182371#44182371         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572398/how-do-i-create-an-editable-label-in-javafx-2-2

Comment: What's about `Wrap Text` ?

Comment: Menai Ala Eddine, `Wrap Text` is not aligning text vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it by creating a `Label`, placing it behind `TextArea`, making it invisible(just in case) and binding TextArea height to label:

```
@FXML
private TextArea msg;

@FXML
private Label bindingText;

@FXML
private Button button; 


@FXML
private void initialize() {
    bindingText.textProperty().bind(msg.textProperty());
    msg.setText(Word.customTranslate("data_transfer_failed", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
    msg.prefHeightProperty().bind(bindingText.heightProperty());
    button.setText(Word.customTranslate("close_app", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
    }
```

Get rid of `TextArea` borders through styling and center it. This way I got centered text, that can also be selected.
[image]